# How to fetch varbinary column data with pdo

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

Hello all I have difficulty to fetch a `varbinary(7680)` column with `pdo`, i use sqlv server. This is a table containing information about player items.
This is my attempt to bring result.

```
$check_ware = $chup->prepare("Select Items from warehouse where AccountID = :useracc");
$check_ware->bindParam(":useracc", $useracc);
$check_ware->execute();
$check_ware_ss = $check_ware->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

I get this `Fatal error: Invalid sql_display_size`

Comment: I'm dealing with a very similar issue, except I'm trying to compare to a `varbinary`. Did you find a solution to your problem?